# Adapterview click event

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, adapter

the problem im having with the xamarin android application is that once i call the click event on any item in the adapter it will work but it calls more than just the one i clicked, Meaning for example i click share and the share intent will show up but more than just once for multiple items in the listview adapter. Here is the code in the adapter. Let me know how to fix this please. i have tried delegates and even going to the extent of disabling the other listview items on click

Code:

```
namespace NameSpace
{
    public class dashboardAdapter : BaseAdapter<DashboardLINQ>
    {
        List<DashboardLINQ> items;
        Activity context;
        string mid;
        public dashboardAdapter(Activity context, List<DashboardLINQ> items)
            : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override DashboardLINQ this[int position]
        {
            get { return items[position]; }
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) 
            {
                view = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.dashboardItemLayout, null, false);
            }

            ImageView prof = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
            Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable (prof, "http://www.mymentor.org.za/"+items [position].uPicLocal);

            mid = items [position].MID;

            TextView usrname = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView1);
            usrname.Text = items [position].uFullName;

            TextView date = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView2);
            date.Text = items [position].pDate;

            ImageView imagen = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView2);
            Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable (imagen, "http://www.mymentor.org.za/"+items [position].pImage);

            TextView desc = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView3);
            desc.Text = Html.FromHtml (items [position].pDesc).ToString();

            TextView comlike = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView4);
            comlike.Text = "Likes: "+items [position].likecnumrows+"    Comments: "+items [position].commentscnumrows;

            ImageButton like = view.FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.button1);
            ImageButton comment = view.FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.button2);
            ImageButton share = view.FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.button3);

            like.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                Uri uri = new Uri("url");
                NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
                parameters.Add("UID", items[position].MID);
                parameters.Add("PID", items[position].ID);
                client.UploadValuesAsync(uri, parameters);
                like.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ButtonComment);
            };


            share.Focusable = false;
            share.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
            share.Clickable = true;

            share.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                int MaxLength = 150;

                var name = Html.FromHtml (items [position].pDesc).ToString();
                if (name.Length > MaxLength) {
                    name = name.Substring(0, MaxLength) + "... My Mentor";
                }

                var myIntent = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
                myIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, name);
                myIntent.SetType("text/plain");
                this.context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(myIntent,"Choose an App"));
            };

            return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: That occurs,because Android re-use rows. You can try to use ViewHolder pattern.ill show how to do this later.

Comment: @VetaLio please. Been struggling with this the whole day.

Comment: @VetaLio Im Giong to test it now

Comment: should work,because that is 100% correctly way :)

Comment: @VetaLio Worked 100%

Comment: @VetaLio Going throught the testing some more now. It no longer opens duplicates although now it displays the wrong information. For example it displays a different rows info?? any thoughts

Comment: See my example. holder.Txt.Text = _Items[position]; (where is located this part)
Your "information" need to put outside.

Comment: @VetaLio I see. What happens when i have to reference the data in the onclick event however? I think that is the problem im having

Comment: like your .SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ButtonComment); in Click event? You mean this?

Comment: @VetaLio No not that. The issue I'm having is that now I am creating a normal toast notification to display the profile name of the title and image I click. This profile name is part of the data I call from the items array. It displays it incorrectly however

Comment: hmmm. Make new question and we will see that issue(for more details). Ill try to implement same thing,what are doing you ;)

Comment: @VetaLio So been debugging to try and figure it out on my own. The position is getting returned incorrectly. I am still testing if i dont get it right today i will create a new question and link it to you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619624/adapter-view-on-click-event-returning-incorrect-position     Making sure you get it @VetaLio

Comment: done,also upmarked your questions ;) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens,because Android reusing rows and calling GetView method **many** times(for e.g. when you scroll your listview,Android automatically fire up GetView to draw hided items and that why your "Clicks" repeats).

So you can try to use **ViewHolder Pattern**.
Check this out(my little example):
*Code of MainLayout.axml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lst" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*And ListItem.axml*

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <TextView
            android:text="Text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        <Button
            android:text="PUSH ME"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Push"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OnCreate()** method

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

                      ListView lst = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lst);

            List<string> Data = new List<string>();
            Data.Add("Prosto GG");
            Data.Add("Prosto GG");
            Data.Add("Prosto GG");
            Data.Add("Prosto GG");
            Data.Add("Prosto GG");
            Data.Add("Prosto GG");
            Data.Add("Prosto GG");
            Data.Add("Prosto GG");
            Data.Add("Prosto GG");
            Data.Add("Prosto GG");
            Data.Add("Prosto GG");
            Data.Add("Prosto GG");
            Data.Add("Prosto GG");
            Data.Add("Prosto GG");
            Data.Add("Prosto GG");
            Data.Add("Prosto GG");
            CustomAdapter cst = new CustomAdapter(Data, this);
            lst.Adapter = cst;

        }
    }
```

And main part of this post,***CustomAdapter*** class:

```
class CustomAdapter: BaseAdapter<string>
    {
        Dialog alertDialog;
        int count = 0;
        List<string> _Items;
        Context _context;
        public CustomAdapter(List<string> Items,Context context)
        {
            this._Items = Items;
            this._context = context;
        }

        #region implemented abstract members of BaseAdapter
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            ServiceViewHolder holder = null;

            var view = convertView;

            if (view == null)
            {
                ////this is part of ViewHolder pattern,new istance of ViewHolder
                holder = new ServiceViewHolder();
                view = LayoutInflater.From(_context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListItem, null);
                holder.Txt = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt);
                holder.PushME = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Push);
                 //put your handler here,in this block of code,like this
                holder.PushME.Click += (sender, e) => 
                    {
                        count++;
                        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
                        builder.SetTitle("test");

                        builder.SetMessage(holder.Txt.Text + " " + count);
                        builder.SetCancelable(false);

                        builder.SetPositiveButton("OK", new EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>((sender1, e2) =>
                            { 
                                alertDialog.Dismiss();
                            }));
                        alertDialog = builder.Create();
                        alertDialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        alertDialog.Show();
                    };
                view.Tag = holder;
            }
            else
            {
                holder = view.Tag as ServiceViewHolder;
            }
            holder.Txt.Text = _Items[position];

            return view;
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return _Items.Count;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region implemented abstract members of BaseAdapter
        public override string this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
               return _Items[index];
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }

    public class ServiceViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public Button PushME { get; set; }

        public TextView Txt { get; set; }

    }
```

So if you want to use this pattern,you must to do:

1. Make class and define the properties of your controls(List Item)
2. just put your handlers in block of code,where view is null(see code below)

Your case looks like:

```
if(view == null)
        {
           //inflate layout and other stuff. 
           holder.like.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                        WebClient client = new WebClient();
                        Uri uri = new Uri("url");
                        NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
                        parameters.Add("UID", items[position].MID);
                        parameters.Add("PID", items[position].ID);
                        client.UploadValuesAsync(uri, parameters);
                        holder.like.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ButtonComment);
                    };  

          //etc
        }
```

For more detail information,read this [**article**](https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-highly-performant-smooth-scrolling-android-listviews/) !
Enjoy.